# What exactly is affecting how fs.writeFile behaves when using async/await in a loop requiring a callback such as Array.map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, fs

This issue appears to be related to string length but I have seen it occur when including a `console.log()` in certain places of the code. To be clear, this issue only occurs when using `fs.writeFile` in a loop that requires a callback such as `Array.map`.

I am able to loop through an array and make a series of (asynchronous) `fs.WriteFile` calls with strings of seemingly any size with as many `console.log()` calls as I like when I use a `for` loop and there is no issue. The expected result is that, by the end of the loop, the file written to contains only the data from the last element of the array. Everything works great. You can check it out on [here on repl.it](https://repl.it/@Devz3n/AsyncAwaitWriteFileSimplified). And here is the code:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const writeFile = (uri, data, options) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.writeFile(uri, data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(`Error writing file: ${uri} --> ${err}`)
    }
    resolve(`Successfully wrote file: ${uri}  --> with data: ${data}`)
  })
})

const asyncWriteFile = (uri, data) => {
  return writeFile(uri, data).then( res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
const asyncWriteFileLoop = async (uri, seed) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++) {
    await asyncWriteFile(uri, seed[i])
  }
}

const uri = 'test-write-dump.txt'
const dataArr = [
  'this is string long enough to cause an issue when using Array.map but not in a for loop',[1,2,3,4],1600,'foobar',['foo','bar','baz']
]

// works as expected, output in file is foo,bar,baz
asyncWriteFileLoop(uri, dataArr)
```

**Now here is the issue**: As soon as I try to replace the `for` loop with `Array.map` using `Promise.all`. The file is appended rather than overwritten and in a seemingly odd and unpredictable order. I realize this is the nature of calling `fs.writeFile` too quickly in a row. However I was expecting the array of promises to resolve one after the other thus circumventing the issue but this appears not to be the case. You can check it out on [here on repl.it](https://repl.it/@Devz3n/AsyncAwaitWriteFileArrayMapSimplified). Here is the offending code:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const writeFile = (uri, data, options) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.writeFile(uri, data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(`Error writing file: ${uri} --> ${err}`)
    }
    resolve(`Successfully wrote file: ${uri}  --> with data: ${data}`)
  })
})

const appendFile = (uri, data, options) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.appendFile(uri, data, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(`Error appending file: ${uri} --> ${err}`)
    }
    resolve(`Successfully appended file: ${uri}  --> with data: ${data}`)
  })
})

asyncWriteFileMap = async (uri, seed) => {
  const promises = seed.map(async data => {
    await writeFile(uri, data)
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  })
  const result = await Promise.all(promises)
}

const uri = 'test-write-dump.txt'
const dataArr = [
  'This is a string long enough to cause an issue, change this to a single character and the expected result almost always occurs',[1,2,3,4],1600,'foobar',['foo','bar','baz']
]

// Seems like it doesnt work with long strings, writes a junk file
asyncWriteFileMap(uri, dataArr)
```

I would really like to know *exactly* what is causing this behavour, why `for` loops work and `Array.map` doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` is NOT promise-aware.  It does not pay any attention to the promise that your callback returns.  Instead, it just puts the promise in the resulting array and continues with its loop.

So, what happens is that `.map()` starts all the `writeFileAsync()` calls at once and then sometime later each of those promises finishes.  The `await` you're using inside the callback does not pause the `.map()` iteration - in fact, it doesn't really help you at all.

The `for` loop, on the other hand, is promise-aware and will pause the loop for the `await`.

So, the `for` loop is paused by the `await`, the `.map()` loop is not.

---

In case, you didn't realize, when an `async` function (like your `.map()` callback) encounters its first `await`, the `async` function immediately returns a promise.  It suspends further function execution until the `await` sees a resolved promise, but the function itself returns a promise and execution of the calling code continues.  That's why `.map()` continues with the rest of its iterations and does not wait for the `await`.

Also, keep in mind that `Promise.all()` doesn't "run" anything.  The asynchronous operations are already running and `Promise.all()` is just given an array of promises to monitor and collect results from.  So, it's not correct to say that `Promise.all()` runs in parallel, not in a specific order.  It is `.map()` that is doing that in your example.

`Promise.all()` is usually used in circumstances when multiple promise-based asynchronous operations are being run in parallel, but those operations are started by something else.  `Promise.all()` is just monitoring the completion and collecting results.

Comment: I thought there was a way to do this and I was following an accepted practice. What about this [codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/NWPgxpP?editors=1111)? I was using the approach listed [here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/).

Comment: @apena - `.map()` with asynchronous operation inside its callback will run them in parallel.  You use `Promise.all()` on the resulting array of promises to know when they are all done, but they don't run/complete in any specific order.  They are started in order, but all run in parallel and can finish in any order.  Use a `for` loop with `await` if you want to sequence your asynchronous loop.  That's the simple way to code it.  For asynchronous operations, the modern `for` loop with `await` is so much more powerful than `.map()`, or `.forEach()`.

Comment: @apena - That article is not explaining the consequences in execution timing of using `await` with `.map()`.  You can do it as long as you want to run all your asynchronous operations in parallel and you use `Promise.all()` on the resulting array of promises to know when they are all done and to get access to all the results.  That structure will NOT sequence the asynchronous operations one after another.  It runs them in parallel.

Comment: Ah thank you. `Promise.all()` runs in parallel not in specific order, this is the crux of the issue. Could you put that in your answer? I will then accept it.

Comment: @apena - `Promise.all()` doesn't "run" anything.  The asynchronous operations are already running and `Promise.all()` is just given an array of promises to monitor and collect results from.  So, it's not correct to say that `Promise.all()` runs in parallel, not in a specific order.  It is `.map()` that is doing that.  I will put this in my answer.